# como consigo el valor de una variable dentro de un metodo c#?

Tags: c#, .net

Buenas tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
     class a{

     static public string convertir() {

     string num = "4";

     return num;
     }

     static public void descargar() {


      Console.WriteLine(convertir());


     }

     static public Main(){

         convertir();
         descargar();


  }
```

En el metodo descargar(), quiero conseguir el valor de la variable num como puedo hacerlo he probado con el return??

Comment: Supongo que tendrás esta clase dentro de una clase Program y que no será un proyecto de tipo librería o similar. Si no es así, no te va a ejecutar. En .NET, tal como lo tienes escrito estás generando una clase llamada `a` con un método estático `Main` pero así ni siquiera va a comenzar la ejecución.

Comment: si correcto es un ejmeplo pero todo esta englobado en la clase program y y el namespace ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El codigo que publicas esta correcto, `convertir()` define un `string` como respuesta, solo que es por medio del metodo `descargar()` que imprimes el valor en pantalla.

Quizas si quiere obtener el valor debas igualarlo a una variable y no ponerlo directo en el `Console.WriteLine()`, usando

```
string result = convertir();
Console.WriteLine("Main - Convertir: {0}", result);
```

Si quieres recuperarlo en el `Main()` usarias

```
class a
{

    static public string convertir() 
    {
        string num = "4";
        return num;
    }

    static public void descargar() 
    {
        string num = convertir();
        Console.WriteLine("descargar: {0}", num);
    }

    static public Main()
    {
        string result = convertir();
        Console.WriteLine("Main - Convertir: {0}", result);
        descargar();
    }
}
```

Comment: nada tio no funciona

Comment: si pones un breakpoint en el codigo se detiene ?

Comment: no entiendo para que quiero detener la ejecucion

Comment: ehh sabes lo que es depurar el codigo? no puedes siquiera empezar a programar sin conocer los basico como hacer el debug, lo quieres detener para poder analizar que esta sucediendo

Comment: si sirve el problema venia porque estaba metido dentro de un if y entoces el return no pillaba la variable como es debido

Comment: aahh ok, en el codigo que publicaste no veo ningun if

Answer (score 0):

si quieres obtener el valor del método debes establecer un tipo de retorno y no un `void`.
Cambia así la definición de tu método

```
public static string convertir() 
{

   string num = "4";

   return num;
 }
```

Comment: si lo tenia asi en mi codigo pero nada no me muestra nada por pantalla